# No Output From cProfile

Tags: python, cprofile

I'm trying to profile an application written using PySide and OpenCV and am getting strange behaviour with the profiler. I run my code using the following line:

```
python -m cProfile -o output.file repo/src/application_window.py
```

It tends to work for very short runs of the program. If I open it and load an image (it's an animation editor), output.file appears as expected. However, if I actually use the program (move through animation frames, etc.) there is no output. It generates no error messages or crash information - just nothing. The same problem occurs if I try to write the results to the console - sometimes it just produces no output.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Edit: The call terminates as expected - but produces no output. It doesn't hang.

Edit2 - Here is the main function of application_window.py:

```
def main():
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    editor = Editor(sys.argv[0])
    editor.show()

    sys.exit(a.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Editor is a fairly complicated QT Widget. So all application_window really does is start the QT event loop.

Comment: It terminates when expected, but with no output.

Comment: Does `python application_window.py` run on command line?

Comment: Nope, it's a GUI application (it basically opens a QT Widget and displays that).

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I have the same issue with a PySide6 application

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for this behavior is that the file gets created at the end of the run. The current directory of the process may at that point be a place you don't expect (or even a directory where the file can't be created). The quickest way to see if this is your problem is to leave out the `-o output.file`. cProfile then writes the profile to stdout. You can also try specifying an absolute path, e.g. `-o /var/tmp/output.file`.